# How to find this ODE solution $f''(x)+x^2f(x)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My idea: For $f(x)\neq 0$, we have

$$ \dfrac{f''(x)}{f(x)}=-x^2. $$

Note that

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx}\left( \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)=\dfrac{f''(x)f(x)-[f'(x)]^2}{[f(x)]^2}=\dfrac{f''(x)}{f(x)} - \left( \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right)^2. $$

Now let $u(x)=\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$. It follows that,

$$\dfrac{du}{dx}+u^2=-x^2.$$

But this way all I can do is getting this Ricatti equation.

Comment: I wonder if some version of variation of parameters with $f(x) = g(x) \cos(x^2/2) + h(x) \sin(x^2/2)$ might end up working?  (With $\cos(x^2/2)$ chosen so that its second derivative is at least close to $-x^2 \cos(x^2/2)$.)

Comment: Did you try power series?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the power series solutions would be $1 - \frac{x^4}{4\cdot 3} + \frac{x^8}{8 \cdot 7 \cdot 4 \cdot 3} - \frac{x^{12}}{12 \cdot 11 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 4 \cdot 3} + \cdots$ and $x - \frac{x^5}{5\cdot 4} + \frac{x^9}{9 \cdot 8 \cdot 5 \cdot 4} - \cdots$.  It wouldn't surprise me if those can be expressed as hypergeometric functions, but I'm not familiar enough myself with those to say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions are two linearly independent standard Parabolic cylindric functions:
$$D_{-1/2}~[(-1+i)x], D_{-1/2}~[(1+i)x].$$
This ODE is actually a special case of one of the Weber's equations. In physics it is Schroedinger equation to study the zero energy scattering at the parabolic potential barrier $V(x)=-x^2.$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeberDifferentialEquations.html